# Sending frames in java

Tags: java, networking, frames, send

Can I send raw frames (low-level internet packets) in java ?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw frames"? IP packets, Ethernet packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a wrapper around libpcap [here](http://jnetpcap.com/) that will allow you to send raw IP packets.

The standard Java java libraries only provides an API for UDP and TCP.