# How can I read or get the information of the beacon frame that sent by the Access point in WLAN, by java or Android?

Tags: java, android

I am just new in Andoird, i am work on android wireless applicationa. So now, i have a problem to get the timestamp of sending beacon frame by an access point, regards... for all...

Halgurd Maghdid
Iraq

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class (who gives you all the information you can have on the WiFi state, see [WifiInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html)), doesn't provide this parameter.

Maybe you can magic something up with a rooted phone, but I don't thing you can do it on a standard

Comment: Thanks dear Vivien Barousse
I tried to do something like that (i.e. using WifiInfo or WifiManager), but i didn't found a method to get the timestampe of the access point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with the standard Libarys as they don't allow access to the raw frames, however, this queston (about accessing raw frames in Java) says their is a wrapper for libpcap which **may** work (I haven't tryed it)

(see [Sending frames in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168898/sending-frames-in-java/2168939#2168939))