# sending and receiving data to board connected through LAN

Tags: java

I have a board connected to my PC through the LAN(i.e network port). I know the IP address and port number of both my PC and board.

I came to know that we have to use socket programming but i am not understanding how to use.

How to set up connection between the two using socket and write the data from PC to the board and read back the data from the board back to PC and print it on the screen.

A program for this would be helpful for me.Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending frames in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168898/sending-frames-in-java)

Comment: Since you mention ports I suspect you are talking about tcp/udp packets and not raw ethernet frames.Read about java sockets.

Comment: using destination port number and sending data is about tcp packets or the raw ethernet frames

Comment: can anyone help me with this plz

Answer (score 0):

You should use *Socket*. Take a look here:

- API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html
- Oracle Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/